# User and UserGroups with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle 1.3 and SonataUserBundle that extends it. I have my own bundle that extends SonataUserBundle and inside it I keep my user-admin class and user & user-group entity (along with associated .orm.xml mappings)

My config.yml:

```
parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.user.entity: Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
    sonata.user.admin.group.entity: Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    sonata.user.admin.user.class: Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class:   Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

Both entity classes basically just extend Sonata's user- and group-class. My user-admin class extends Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin.

The problem is that in my /admin, when I list users, I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: groups in
>   /vagrant/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Guesser/FilterTypeGuesser.php
>   line 64

Answer (score 4):

**edit:** As @Hemang pointed it out, my first answer wasn't very explicit. So I corrected it

In order to get the correct mapping for your user entity you have to enable the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.

To do that, juste edit your AppKernel.php and add the line

```
new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle()
```

in the registerBundles function.

Here is a working AppKernel.php exemple :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{

  public function registerBundles()
  {
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),

        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
      $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
      $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
      $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
  }

  public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
  {
    $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble ... I think the sonata user configurator does not register the doctrine mapping ... https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SonataUserExtension.php#L249

As workaround I added the many to many relation to my custom user entity

```
namespace  Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity

class User
{

    ...

    /**                                                 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")            
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group")       
     */                                                 
    protected  $groups;                                 
}
```

Comment: This works fine temporarily, however there should be a better fix for this. The sandbox works fine.

Comment: The correct fix is to add the SonataEasyExtendsBundle to AppKernel ... I think the @Mait solution is better.